# Python based PDF search using BING web-search API

Tags: python-2.7, bing-api

I want to retrieve related pdf from keywords using bing API. But I am facing some issues.

keywords list :

```
"Hubble Space Telescope", "William Herschel", "Planetary Camera", "Milky Way"
```

I am following this code:

```
 import requests

subscription_key = "My Key"
assert subscription_key

search_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search"
search_term = ["Hubble Space Telescope", "William Herschel", "Planetary Camera", "Milky Way"]

result=[]
for i in range(len(search_term)):
    headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}
    params  = {"q": search_term[i],"filetype":"pdf", "textDecorations":True, "textFormat":"HTML"}
    response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    search_results = response.json()
    print search_results
    result.append(search_results)


from IPython.display import HTML

for i in range(len(result)):
    rows = "\n".join(["""<tr><td><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></td><td>{2}</td>
                    </tr>""".format(v["url"].encode("utf-8"),v["name"].encode("utf-8"),v["snippet"].encode("utf-8")) \
                      for v in result[i]["webPages"]["value"]])

HTML("<table>{0}</table>".format(rows))

print rows
```

Though I added filetype: pdf in params section but not getting any pdf.

Can anyone suggest me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Include `"filetype:pdf"` as part of the search term, not as a separate query string parameter.